# Find the distribution of $X_t|Y_t,X_{t-1}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Find the distribution of  $X_t|Y_t,X_{t-1}$ given 
$$X_t=\alpha X_{t-1}+V_t$$
$$Y_t=X_t+\sigma_wW_t$$
where $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, $V_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$, and $W_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$.

I was trying that 
$$X_t|X_{t-1} \sim N(\alpha x_{t-1},1)$$
$$Y_t|X_t \sim N(X_t, \sigma^2_w)$$
But how to get the distribution of  $X_t|Y_t,X_{t-1}$? Thanks~

Comment: Hint: From your lecture notes, this conditional distribution is normal hence it suffices to find the conditional mean and the conditional variance.